# How to use save the cookie and reuse it in YouTube studio

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, youtube, browser-automation

Can someone explain how to save the cookies and use them in the same domain. I got stuck in here.

I am using the chrome browser to login to YouTube then I need to save the cookies and reuse them while uploading video. I just wrote a code but for me it say the cookies expired.

please help me out with it.

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pickle

if __name__ == '__main__':
    email = "youtube_is"
    password = "password"

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #options.add_argument('proxy-server=106.122.8.54:3128')
    options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=selenium')

    browser = uc.Chrome(
        options=options,
    )
    browser.get("https://studio.youtube.com")

    browser.find_element(By.ID, 'identifierId').send_keys(email)

    browser.find_element(
        By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#identifierNext > div > button > span').click()

    password_selector = "#password > div.aCsJod.oJeWuf > div > div.Xb9hP > input"


    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, password_selector)))


    browser.find_element(
        By.CSS_SELECTOR, password_selector).send_keys(password)

    browser.find_element(
        By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#passwordNext > div > button > span').click()
    
    time.sleep(5)
    cookie = browser.get_cookies()
    pickle.dump(cookie, open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))
```

Saved form here

and reuse here.

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pickle

if __name__ == '__main__':
    browser = uc.Chrome()
    browser.get("https://studio.youtube.com")

    cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))

    for cookie in cookies:
        cookie['domain'] = "studio.youtube.com"
        try:
            browser.add_cookie(cookie)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    # s = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/input')
    # time.sleep(3)
    # s.send_keys("C:\\Users\\yazha\\Videos\\demo.mp4")
```